# How to Launch Visual Studio from the Command Line? How to add reference to assembly? to EnvDTE?

Tags: .net, powershell, visual-studio, command-line, envdte

I'm following along to [Launch Visual Studio using DTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/launch-visual-studio-dte?view=vs-2022) which has the following steps:

1. Create a new Console App project for the .NET Framework.
2. Install the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Interop NuGet package and **add a reference to the assembly.**
3. **Add a reference to EnvDTE.**
4. Paste the example code that follows into the Program.cs file.
5. Press F5 to run the program. You should see Visual Studio 2019 open before the program exits.

How do I do:

- **add a reference to the assembly.**
- **Add a reference to EnvDTE.**

Is it referring to adding references to the `.csproj` file? Suing `dotnet add reference (package|reference) <something>`?